# Selenium how to get the size of text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is different from the question of "how to get the size of the element that contains some text". I can get the size of the element that contains text using Selenium webdriver, and that's not the problem. The problem is, if the element contains some text, then some child element, e.g. a span, which also contains text, then how do I get the size of the first segment of text, without including the child element?

In Chrome, you can in fact see the size of the first segment of text, if you use developer tools and select that segment, and then hover on it. It would pop up a tooltip that says, e.g. "#text 92x40" which gives width and height.

example image here:

[image: Tooltip with text size example]

But the question is how can I obtain that information from Selenium. Preferably in Python.

I will also add a note to clarify: as far as I know, Selenium cannot select the `text()` in the select_by_xpath method. It can only select up to the parent element. This means if the text of interest, the first segment of text, is of xpath `\div\div\text()[1]`, using Selenium I can only select up to `\div\div`, and that's why I can't find its width. The child span element, on the other hand, can be selected with `\div\div\span`, whose width can then be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get size of child element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[.='carefully scrutinise the government\'']")
width = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].offsetWidth", element)
```

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't that select the parent element of the text, not the text itself?

Comment: Depends on locator you’ll use. If you use right locator for the child element, code I shared will give you the width of it.